# A palavra "chor" (= ‘flor’) existe no português? Por que não foi atestada no português antigo?

Tags: dialetos, reconstruções

A palavra *chor*, derivada do latim "florem", é um cognato e sinônimo de "flor" que, diferente desta, teria sofrido em sua evolução a alteração fonética que transformou os **"fl-, pl-, cl-"** do latim em **"ch-"** (como *"afflare > achar"*, *"planum > chão"*, *"clamare > chamar'*, etc).

Segundo o [Wikcionario anglófono](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Old_Portuguese/chor), a palavra **chor* na língua Galego-Portuguesa é uma reconstrução, ou seja, ela não é atestada em escritos antigos, e se trata de uma palavra hipotética. Por outro lado, a palavra "flor" é atestada em vários textos antiquíssimos da língua, como nas [Cantigas de escárnio e maldizer](https://pt.wikisource.org/w/index.php?search=incategory%3A"Cantigas+de+esc%C3%A1rnio+e+maldizer"+flor) e nas [Cantigas de Santa Maria](https://pt.wikisource.org/w/index.php?search=intitle%3A"Cantigas+de+santa+maria"+flor). Outra forma, "[fror](https://pt.wikisource.org/w/index.php?search=intitle%3A"Cantigas+de+santa+maria"+fror)", também era comum.

Já no Português moderno, o [Wikcionário lusófono](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/chor) e o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/chor) dizem que *"chor"* é um termo dialetal transmontano e um arcaísmo, respectivamente. E no Galego moderno, o [Dicionario da Real Academia Galega](http://academia.gal/dicionario/-/termo/chor) diz que é uma alternativa para "flor".

Há algumas flores que usam o radical *chor* e que poderiam ser derivadas desta:

- A *"[chorima](http://academia.gal/dicionario/-/termo/busca/chorima)"*, ou *"[chorida](http://academia.gal/dicionario/-/termo/chorida)"*, tal como chamada na Galiza (e talvez no norte de Portugal) as flores do [tojo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tojo). A chorima é, inclusive, a [flor nacional da Galiza](http://converxencia.eu/?page_id=442).
- O *"[chorão-das-praias](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpobrotus_edulis)"*.

Há também uma árvore (e não uma flor) chamada Salgueiro-chorão, mas que cujas folhas caídas [como se as tivessem chorando](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/Willow.jpg) a fizeram ser derivada do verbo "chorar" e não do substantivo "chor". Compare com o francês "*[saule pleureur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saule_pleureur)*" (literalmente "salgueiro chorador"), na qual o verbo latino "plorare" manteve o "pl-" inicial; com os outros cognatos nas línguas românicas (como o espanhol "sauce llorón"); ou com o inglês "*[weeping willow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salix_babylonica)*", que tem a mesma tradução literal.

Primeiramente, por que esta palavra é reconstruída no português antigo? Quero dizer, há algum motivo para não encontrarmo-la no corpus medieval do Português, mas encontrarmos porém as palavras "flor, fror, frol" (que eram basicamente diferentes realizações da mesma palavra "flor", já que a variação /l~r/ ocorria naquela época)?

Esta palavra realmente existe atualmente na língua? Isto é, ela é usada, mesmo que dialetalmente (em Trás-os-Montes, tal como proposto pelo dicionário)? Ou se trata de uma palavra arcaica? Se for uma palavra arcaica, quando ela foi usada e atestada até entrar em desuso, já que ela não é atestada nos textos medievais?

Comment: A ter existido essa *chor*, fica explicado o *chorão*, uma flor comum perto de praias. Sempre associei a *chorar*, pela forma da palavra, mas nunca percebi nenhuma relação no sentido. Nós dizemos *à flor da pele, à flor da água*, 'à superfície'. Na cozedura, a gordura acumula-se na superfície da água. Poderia vir daí esse *chorume* (nunca tinha ouvido).

Comment: Alguns dicionários dizem que este "chorão" viria de ["choro/chorar"](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/CHOR%C3%83O), uns livros dizem vir de ["chor/flor"](https://www.lume.ufrgs.br/bitstream/handle/10183/8036/000565418.pdf?sequence=1). Encontrei este provérbio português que não sei se conheces (me soa ser bem antigo): *"No tempo da chôr
é cortar e pôr."*. Aliás, essa minha última questão (do "chorume") apesar de relacionada é paralela à questão principal (da "chor"); seria o caso de eu movê-la para outra pergunta?

Comment: O Houaiss, para a origem de *salgueiro-chorão* manda ver *flor(i)-*, mas eu estou agora convencido que vem de *chorar*. Na verdade, eu referia-me ao *chorão-da-praia*, mas também esse me parece vir de *chorar*. Descobri hoje esse provérbio. Creio que tenho uma explicação razoável para o *chorume*, estou a preparar uma resposta. Seriam possível separa, mas não me parece mal ficar tudo junto.

Comment: Sim, o salgueiro é relacionado a "chorar", e não a "chor" (os cognatos noutras línguas refletem isso). Quanto ao "chorão-de-praia" não achei cognatos (as outras línguas usam nomes com outras etimologias). Adicionei uma terceira planta, a "chorima", que, dentre as três, é a que tem mais relação aparente com "chor" do que com o verbo "chorar". Separei as questões pra poder trabalhar cada uma melhor individualmente.

Comment: Há alguém de Trás-os-Montes aqui que possa confirmar se "chor" (ou ao menos as "choridas") existe por lá?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Procurei por todo o lado, e encontrei um único testemunho direto do uso da palavra *chor* na língua portuguesa, nomeadamente em Valpaços, Trás-os-Montes, numa carta de Joaquim de Castro Lopo publicada em 1895 na Revista Lusitana (vol III, p. 325-29, disponível no [Instituto Camões](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/conhecer/biblioteca-digital-camoes/etnologia-etnografia-tradicoes.html)):

> Nesta minha terceira carta á cêrca do sub-dialecto valpacense completarei as informações que a seu respeito ficaram consignadas nas duas anteriores [p. 325]
>
> […]
>
> **Chor**, flôr. Proverbio referido á plantação da oliveira:
>         No tempo da *chor*
>         É cortar e pôr [p. 327]

Vários autores comentam a palavra, e este é também o único exemplo que mencionam; e parece-me que todos o foram buscar à carta da Revista Lusitana (ver por exemplo [Carlos Rocha no Ciberdúvidas, 2007](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-palavra-flor-no-portugues-antigo/21751)). Outros mencionam explicitamente que não são conhecidas abonações textuais da palavra [(Clarinda A. Maia, “Sobre a perda de palavras medievais”, *Acta del Congresso Internacional de Lingüística*, 2010)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=MMixAdIH_gkC&pg=PA246&dq=%22a%20variante%20heredit%C3%A1ria,%20tradicional,%20char,%20de%20que%20n%C3%A3o%20s%C3%A3o%20conhecidas%20abona%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20textuais%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2gKrg74TXAhWM7BQKHaWrBtYQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20variante%20heredit%C3%A1ria%2C%20tradicional%2C%20char%2C%20de%20que%20n%C3%A3o%20s%C3%A3o%20conhecidas%20abona%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20textuais%22&f=false).

Mas este testemunho, mesmo sendo único, em conjunto com o uso documentado na Galiza, região vizinha de Trás-os-Montes, mostram que a palavra existiu no galego-português antigo, já que o processo que descreveste, passagem do *fl* latino ao *ch* galego-português (outros exemplos são *flama* > *chama*, cidade *Aquae Flaviae* > [*Chaves*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaves_(Portugal)#Top.C3.B3nimos)) ocorreu numa fase muito inicial da formação da língua.

Sobre o substituição de *chor* por *flor* e o facto de *chor* já não aparecer sequer em textos medievais, encontrei apenas conjeturas, mas que me parecem muito plausíveis. Existe consenso que *flor* entrou ou manteve-se na língua por via erudita (Houaiss, Lisboa 2002; [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-palavra-flor-no-portugues-antigo/21751)). O filólogo Leite de Vasconcelos sugere que teria sido em particular “por influencia da Igreja, onde [*flor*] tanto se usa” (*Revista Lusitana*, vol II, 1890-2, p. 371, disponível no [Instituto Camões](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/conhecer/biblioteca-digital-camoes/etnologia-etnografia-tradicoes.html)). O dicionário Houaiss (verbete *flor(i)-*) diz que *chor* “teve contra si a homonímia com o radical *chor-* de *chorar*”. O filólogo Mariño Paz sugere que *flor* tenha sempre concorrido com *chor* e que esta última tenha tido uma difusão limitada:

> a hipótese de que a mudanza fonética [...] talvez só alcanzou o substantivo flor e os seus derivados unha difusión limitada xeográfica, social e/ou contextualmente, de tal maneira que as variantes conservadoras (con [fl-]) se acharían nunha situación que lles permitiria prevalecer sobre as innnovadoras, de tal xeito que xa no século XIII serían as propias do uso lingüístico común. *Flor* poderia ser unha variante conservadora de *chor*. Mariño Paz (2008: 517)
> p. 201
> [Citado em Francisco González Lousada, “O latinismo na lírica medieval galego-portuguesa”, Estudos Linguísticos/Linguistic Studies, 6-7, Edições Colibri/CLUNL, Lisboa, 2012, pp. 195-208.](http://www.clunl.edu.pt/resources/docs/revista/n6_7/195_208.pdf)

Não encontrei qualquer vestígio de *chorima* ou *chorida* em Portugal. Mas existe, ou existiu, *chorecer* com o significado de *florescer*. Diz Carolina Michaëlis de Vasconcellos (*Revista Lusitana*, vol. III, 1895, p. 140, [Instituto Camões](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/conhecer/biblioteca-digital-camoes/etnologia-etnografia-tradicoes.html)):

> Sá de Miranda emprega uma vez o provincialismo (minhoto, galego) *chorecer*, por *florecer*

[Sá de Miranda (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1_de_Miranda) morreu em 1558, portanto é coisa antiga. Não é claro do que ela diz se *chorecer* continuava em uso na altura, mas o dicionário de Cândido de Figueiredo de 1899 classifica a palavra como “termo antigo”.

Comment: Eu havia procurado bastante por essa palavra, mas não encontrei qualquer uso direto que não seja em dicionário ou comentário sobre a palavra. Não consegui encontrar também se "chor" é ainda usado no dialeto Transmontano, mas pelas datas das fontes, creio que a palavra já esteja morta por lá.

Comment: @Seninha, bem, a carta na revista lusitana é o mais próximo de uso direto que encontrei. Também me parece que a palavra já não está em uso. Mesmo no galego parece-me ser muito rara. Não encontrei quase nada.