# Etimologia de "chorume"

Tags: etimologia

A palavra portuguesa e galega "***chorume***" possui as seguintes definições (ver dicionários portugueses [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/chorume), [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/chorume), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=chorume); e galegos [Real Academia¹](http://academia.gal/dicionario/-/termo/chorume), [Digalego¹](http://digalego.xunta.gal/digalego/Html/muestra_palabra.php?op=ver&dominio=digalego.xunta.gal&buscado=chorume)):

1. Gordura que ressuma (i.e., sai em forma de gotas/suor) da carne animal.
2. Resíduo líquido derivado da estrumeira que enriquece o adubo.
3. Resíduo líquido derivado da decomposição de matéria orgânica no lixo.
4. Alguns dicionários dão uma quarta definição, figurativa, de chorume como *"grande quantidade, abundância, fartura, riqueza, importância"*, mas particularmente nunca ouvi este sentido em uso, e não imagino como algo relacionado a lixo orgânico e esterco pode denotar algo positivo como "fartura e riqueza". Outro sentido figurado, que não é descrito por esses dicionários mas que vejo ser muito popular na Internet brasileira, é como uma tradução do inglês *"[bullshit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bullshit)"* ou como "a porcaria que sobra de algo" (por exemplo, *"Este vídeo é cheio de chorume!"*, ou *"Aquele jornal é só o chorume da notícia!"*).

Quanto às etimologias propostas desta palavra, há:

- **De *florume*:** Os dicionários [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/chorume), [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/chorume), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=chorume) e [Digalego¹](http://digalego.xunta.gal/digalego/Html/muestra_palabra.php?op=ver&dominio=digalego.xunta.gal&buscado=chorume) dizem que *chorume* veio da raiz *[chor](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/a-palavra-chor-existe-no-portugu%c3%aas-porqu%c3%aa-n%c3%a3o-foi-atestada-no-portugu%c3%aas-antig)*, forma arcaica (dialetal e/ou reconstruída) de *flor*, pelo latim *"florumen"*. Aqui há duas opções: ou chorume veio de algum "florume" que já existia (no latim ou no português antigo), ou veio da adição original de "chor" (flor) ao sufixo "-ume". O [«Hipótesis etimológicas referentes al gallego-portugés»](http://sli.uvigo.es/ddd/ddd_pescuda.php?pescuda=chorume&tipo_busca=lema), de Aníbal Otero, diz que a palavra latina "florumen", da qual "chorume" viria, é uma palavra hipotética (isto é, reconstruída). O [«Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa»](https://archive.org/stream/AntenorNascentesDicionaroEtimologicoDaLinguaPortuguesaTomoI/DicionarioEtimolgicoDaLinguaPortuguesa#page/n153/mode/2up), de Antenor Nascentes, diz que "florumen" se referia a uma tal "flor de ferro". Não consegui encontrar tal flor, mas encontrei as *"[chorimas](https://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorima)"*, que são como se chamam na Galiza as flores do [Tojo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tojo), que têm a mesma etimologia de "chor", mas não sei se tratam-se dessas tais "flores de ferro".
- **De *chorume¹*:** I.e., de "choro + -ume", onde este choro vem do verbo "chorar". Não encontrei nenhum dicionário que proponha esta etimologia, nem se trata de uma etimologia popular (como "cheirume", abaixo).
- **De *chorume²*:** O «Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa» dá a possibilidade de "chorume" vir de "choro". Este "choro", por sua vez, viria do latim "jus, juris" (suco da carne), que originou o inglês "juice" por via do francês.
- **De *cheirume*:** Esta é uma etimologia popular, de que "chorume" veio de "cheiro + -ume", no sentido de que, os resíduos do esterco e do lixo em decomposição são malcheirosos, e o sufixo "-ume" daria a conotação ruim ao radical "cheiro". A palavra "cheirume" de fato existe tanto no português ([Dicionário Informal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/cheirume/) e [Blogue dos Enxidros](http://dosenxidros.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/o-nosso-falar-cheirume.html)) quanto no galego ([Real Academia²](http://academia.gal/dicionario/-/termo/cheirume), [Digalego²](http://digalego.xunta.gal/digalego/Html/muestra_palabra.php?op=ver&dominio=digalego.xunta.gal&buscado=cheirume) e [vários outros dicionários](http://sli.uvigo.es/ddd/ddd_pescuda.php?pescuda=cheirume&tipo_busca=lema)) com os mesmos sentidos, mas me parecem ser neologismos. O Wikcionário lista também *[cheirum](http://www.aulete.com.br/cheirum)* e *[cheirúmio](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheir%C3%BAmio)*, mas não encontrei tais palavras fora do Wikcionário.

Minhas dúvidas são:

- De onde veio chorume?
- Como esta palavra poderia ter evoluído de "flor"?
- O que explicaria a semântica variando entre "resíduo líquido de lixo, de carne ou de excremento" e "fartura, riqueza, abundância ou importância"?
- É de se esperar que, quando o sentido duma palavra muda com o tempo, ele evolua gradualmente. Há atestado algum uso da palavra "chorume" com o sentido intermediário entre flor e líquido fétido (se é que isso é possível)?
- O sufixo "-ume", que imagino não ser mais produtivo atualmente (ao menos não é no Português Brasileiro), era usado no latim para criar palavras de conotação pejorativa e coletiva (por exemplo "anticumen = anticus + -umen", *porcarias velhas, velharia*) . Mas ainda assim, não compreendo como isso se aplicaria a chorume (seja pela aplicação direta do sufixo ao radical "chor", ou por um ancestral intermediário "florume" que significara outra coisa).
- Qual seria os casos mais antigos do uso de "chorume" ou "florume(n)" no corpus português ou latino?
- Se um tal "florumen" já existia antes no Latim, o que ele significava? Existem outros cognatos de uma palavra latina "florumen" em outras línguas?

Meu corretor ortográfico aponta "chorume" como inexistente para pt-PT, mas correto para pt-BR. Esta palavra não é tão popular em Portugal quanto aqui?

Comment: Existe *chorumo* em espanhol, com basicamente o mesmo significado, mas a opinião dominante parece ser que veio do português.

Comment: Nos exemplos mais antigos, a partir do sXVI, o que encontro é quase sempre *churume*. No meu sotaque, *churume* e *chorume* são homófonos. Mas creio que no Brasil não são, certo? E em Portugal no sXVI também não seriam. Então isto sugere um radical *chur* e não *chor*. Mas já vi algures que na Galiza existe a variante *chur*. Mas na obras mais antiga, ou uma das obras mais antigas, o autor usa *churume*  [(*Auto da Avé Maria*, 1587, página da esquerda, linha 4)](http://purl.pt/23692/3/#/20), e *chorume* [(p. direita, l. 9)](http://purl.pt/23692/3/#/30). Talvez existissem as duas pronúncias.

Comment: A pronuncia no Brasil depende do dialeto e da rapidez da fala. Na fala descuidada se ouve "churume". Nos dialetos que abrem a vogal da primeira sílaba, se for átona, (falando "cóstúra" em vez de "côstúra") pode haver "chórúme" em vez de "chôrúme", mas nunca ouvi.

Comment: Esses usos antigos da palavra são muito estranhos, não consigo identificar ao que se referiam. O mais plausível seria o 4º sentido dos que citei (fartura, riqueza). Seria esse sentido o original e os outros seus derivados figurados? Mas ainda assim é bastante estranho, nunca ouvi este sentido positivo de riqueza aqui, só sentidos relacionados a lixo, esterco e para difamar alguém.

Comment: E achei este blogue português de jardinagem que o autor fala de chorume (sentido 2. "derivado de esterco, aditivo do adubo"): [Quinta do sargaçal: Larvas no chorume de urtigas](http://www.sargacal.com/2014/05/19/larvas-no-chorume-de-urtigas/). Se aí não for um termo popular, deve ser um termo técnico usado na jardinagem. Há [outras postagens](http://www.sargacal.com/2010/03/24/chorume-de-urtigas-pronto/) no site sobre produção de chorume (*"Se acham o aspecto terrível, deviam estar aqui a cheirar"*).

Comment: A linguagem no Auto da Avé Maria é muito críptica, mas creio que na primeira passagem significa 'riqueza'; na segunda 'juízo'. Em todos os exemplos mais antigos que encontrei, sXVI e sXVII, são estes os significados. Creio no entanto que estes são os sentidos figurados, e que aparecem na literatura porque os assuntos em que figuram são mais interessantes do que gordura na panela.

Comment: Adicionei à pergunta alguns dicionários galegos, já que esta palavra existe em ambas as línguas, dentre os dicionários há um que diz que o ancestral latino de chorume (isto é, "florumen") é hipotético. (Quando fui reeditar acabei me confundindo com as ferramentas e com o Rollback, que nunca tinha usado, e fiz 4 edições numa só. Peço desculpas pela "poluição editorial").

Comment: Também encontrei várias vezes _*florume_, com o asterisco indicador de hipotético. O único possível cognato que encontrei é o italiano *fiorume*, que os dicionários dizem vir de *fiore*, mas atualmente pelo menos significa 'palhinha moída que resta do feno no celeiro", logo sem relação semântica com chorume. Portanto parece-me que a hipótese mais parcimoniosa é que *chorume* e *fiorume* se originaram independentemente.

Comment: Realmente, *"fiorume"* deve ser um cognato morfológico, mas não léxico, de chorume. O italiano possui o sufixo [*"-ume"*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ume) com o mesmo sentido coletivo e pejorativo do "-umen" latino. O Italiano inclusive herda o ["anticumen"](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=anticume) do latim, que eu dei de exemplo na pergunta, e com o sentido também preservado. Imagino que *"fiorume"* teria se desenvolvido de "As sobras da flor/flora" ou "as porcarias que sobram da flor".

Comment: Curioso esse uso em "este vídeo está cheio de chorume". No passado, o significado seria o oposto. Um auto, peça de teatro, com chorume, era um auto com conteúdo, interesse. Eu não estou com tempo para fazer uma resposta. Mas tenho uma porção de citações dos primeiros usos conhecidos e de dicionários antigos, com links, mais umas notas minhas. Se me deres um contacto, eu envio-tas.

Comment: Adoraria ler suas notas e pesquisas! Há links para algumas das minhas redes sociais no meu perfil do stackexchange. Mas você também pode escrevê-las num documento público no [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/), no [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/) ou no [write.as](https://write.as/) para que os outros que lerem essa pergunta tenham acesso (nalguns desses sites é possível marcar a formatação do texto como "Markdown", que é a mesma formatação das perguntas e respostas daqui). De qualquer forma, obrigado pelo tempo que dedicou a pesquisar!

Comment: Ok, enviei-te pelo facebook. Depois vejo isso do pastebin, etc. Se quiseres tu postar o documento, imagino que já tenhas conta e saibas como se faz, tás à vontade.

Comment: Como nativo lusófono, entendo o "chorume" ser o líquido que escorre de sacos de lixo ou depósitos de lixo, como  aterros sanitários. Nesse contexto, a melhor origem para a palavra é realmente a semelhança com lágrimas, o choro.